# How to block Bots excluding crawlers from accessing my site?

Tags: apache, security, bots

A bot crawls my site every few minutes or hours and my site becomes unavailable due to resource shortage. The bot origins from **Russia**.

How do I block this bot from accessing my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved he issue.

The solution:

Check Latest visitors to your domain
Check the user agent which is visiting consistently.

In my case I found **YandexBot**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)
```

Now that you have found the bot which is slowing down your server, go ahead and block it. You can either do it with `robots.txt` or `.htaccess`

`.htaccess` method:

Add the following code in it.

```
#block bad bots with a 403
BrowserMatchNoCase "Yandex" bots
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=bots
```

Or

`robots.txt` method:

Add the following code in it.

```
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /
```

That's it. You've blocked the bot.

Comment: Robots.txt is acted on by the if it wants to and if a bot is disruptive then it's unlikely to bother obeying what's in that. Much better to block in Apache config and/or iptables or firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Deny directive should be inside the files section, try :

```
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
</Files>
```

Alternatively, you could use a mod-rewrite based ip blocking

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.2\.3\.4\.5$
RewriteRule  - [F]
```